# How to configure /etc/maas/maas-proxy.conf?

Tags: 14.04, proxy, maas

is there someone who could help me to set properly MAAS to use a proxy ?

there is a proxy in between MAAS and the internet, How to point MAAS to a different proxy and tell maas-proxy to use an upstream proxy ?

Please I really need help !

Answer (score 0):

In the web UI click on settings, if you scroll down you can specify apt proxy for http/https to pull packages down. I am using 1.9.3 MAAS version.